# How to enable intellisense in package.json

Tags: webstorm, jetbrains-ide

[In this video](https://youtu.be/upgjCMHGpwo?t=23m3s) is shown how WebStorm provides intellisense support in `package.json`. I tried the same but it doesn't work for my version. How do I enable it?

My version is:

```
WebStorm 2016.3.3
Build #WS-163.12024.17, built on January 31, 2017
Licensed to Maximus Koretskyi
You have a perpetual fallback license for this version
Subscription is active until October 16, 2018
JRE: 1.8.0_73-b02 amd64
JVM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM by Oracle Corporation
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that you need to use WebStorm **2017.1** (build 171.2272 or newer) which is currently in EAP stage (the video shows IDE version that was used).

https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2017/01/webstorm-2017-1-eap-171-2272/

Latest EAP build can be downloaded [here](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/WI/WebStorm+EAP).

Comment: thanks, do you know if I need a license for EAP to continously use the IDE? I can't find this information anywhere

Comment: **Each** EAP build for **major** version (as it's now -- 2017.1) comes with with own 30-days license. So by installing newer EAP build gives you another 30 days (from build date). The limit for 30 days is so that people can use is as they wish but would move to a newer version instead of sticking to old build .. as the whole point of EAP builds (from JB side of view) is to have early feedback on possible bugs and mistakes or recently introduced features .. and if you are using old build you may be reporting already fixed/no longer "available" issues.

Comment: thanks a lot for the clear explanation. Do you know how often do they release EAP versions and stable versions?

Comment: Once major version is released (2017.1.0 final in our case) all subsequent EAP builds (e.g. for 2017.1.1) will require valid license/subscription. Then the circle will repeat again with next major 2017.2 version.

Comment: EAP is **usually** released once a week; but sometimes 1 week might be skipped. Although there were periods when it took 3 weeks for next EAP. In any case -- new EAP build will be released before 30-day license from previous will expire. I suggest checking their blog -- they do announcements for every new EAP and stable builds: http://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/

Comment: Stable -- well.. there was 2016.1, 2016.2 & 2016.3 last year .. and they want to keep that cycle (3 major releases per year). How fast minor build is released is unknown for sure -- it all depends on found issues. It may take 1 week for 2017.1.1 .. or may take whole month if nothing critical is found. Latest stable WebStorm is 2016.3.3 as far as I know (PhpStorm is still 2016.3.2 only).

Comment: 2017.1 final is planned to be released at some point next month (at least those were the initial plans voiced even last year). It should be similar to what was with 2016.1 (last year).